# BigInteger returning negative numbers

Tags: java, math, biginteger

why this math return negative numbers for some numbers:

int x = 351;

```
    String bigValue= ((50*x*x*x-150*x*x+400*x)/3) + "";
    BigInteger resultInteger = new BigInteger(bigValue);
    System.out.println(resultInteger);
```

result -> 714612600

but if i use 352

result -> -710900565

for x=500 -> 639244234

WHY?

Comment: You are multiplying and dividing by integers which will overflow at some point.

Answer (score 6):

This line here:

```
(50*x*x*x-150*x*x+400*x)/3
```

Is using integers, which can overflow. If an integer hits the max (2^31-1), it will *overflow* to -2^31.

You need to use BigIntegers here, something like this:

```
Biginteger bx = new BigInteger(x);
BigInteger new BigInteger(50).multiply(bx.pow(3)).multiply(new BigInteger(-150))
    .multiply(bx.pow(2)).multiply(new BigInteger(400)).multiply(bx).divide(3);
```

Comment: so its impossible to do this math? how can i print a very long result? and why for 352 it overflow, and for 500 not?

Comment: I'm updating my answer, give me a second.

Comment: @user2582318 You can use `BigInteger`. By using the `BigInteger` methods, not `new BigInteger(String)`

Comment: It is 2^31-1 to -2^31 for 32bit signed integers.

Comment: @LutzL Thanks, I forgot about the sign bit.